# Firebase: How to Query Local Database Even if Device is Online

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

How to change behavior of firebase querying for server database or locale database.

```
DatabaseReference scoresRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores");
scoresRef.keepSynced(false);
```

Is that possible to make same query for server and than used it from local database. firstly I want to make a query from server database and then without download again and again I want to use same querying datas from local datas even after app is closed.

I am using above codes for using offline firebase and trying to use same datas without download again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

It means that Firebase will create a local copy of the database on user device.  This means that the application will work even if the device temporarily loses its network connection or if the user restarts the application.

So the answer your question is, that the same query that works when you are online will also work when you are offile, because the database which will be queried is the local database. You don't to do other operations.

Comment: assume that I've hunderds of datas and app make a query and get 10 datas of them randomly from firebase database server. how can use it same 10 datas without download again even after app closed and device is online.